# Pass an intermediate filtered range to INDEX MATCH

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of contracts as below.

```
   A   |   B   |   C   | 
-------------------------
   X   |   5   |   7   |
   Y   |   2   |   4   |
   Z   |   1   |   6   |
   Z   |   5   |   8   |
   X   |   3   |   5   |
```

I want to produce a second table.

```
   A   |   B   |   C   | 
-------------------------
   X   |   3   |   7   |
   Y   |   2   |   4   |
   Z   |   1   |   8   |
```

This second table takes all the unique values from column A of the first table, then finds the lowest column B value associated with this unique value, and the highest column C value.

Using INDEX MATCH feels like the way to go, except that the first table isn't sorted by columns B or C.

I've found ways of sorting a range with formulas, but not in a way that I can pass to INDEX MATCH.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like with many Excel questions here, you're trying to reinvent the wheel here for no reason.

Excel already has inbuilt functionality for this. Let me introduce you to the world of **Pivot Tables**

---

1. **Select your table Data like so**

   [image]
2. **Insert Tab -> Pivot Table**

   [image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfmkg.png)
3. **Change the Value of Pivot Fields from `Sum` to `Min` for Column B, and `Max` for Column C**

   [image][image]

---

**Provides Result as Expected:**

[image]

Comment: Some fine hand drawn red circles. Chapeau! Not so sure about that arrow, though...

Comment: @Olly hahahaha yeah, I knew it looked like shit, but was too lazy to re-draw. Well I used to (still ocassionally do) graphic design in photoshop, so at least some form of steady hand always came in ... handy... ;)

Comment: Thanks! Genuinely searched a long time for a solution, but struggled to know how to word the question. Didn't realise I could do this with pivot tables :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use **Power Query** (Get & Transform Data):

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"A"}, {{"B", each List.Min([B]), type number}, {"C", each List.Max([C]), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

You could use a **Pivot Table**:

Field `A` in `ROWS`, Field `B` in `VALUES` (summarized by `Min`), Field `C` in `VALUES` (summarized by `Max`)

Answer (score 1):

One array formula and two standard psuedo-MINIF/MAXIF formulas.

In F2:H2,

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$6, MATCH(0, COUNTIFS(F$1:F1, A$2:A$6), 0))   'array formula
=MIN(INDEX(B$2:B$6+(A$2:A$6<>F2)*1E+99, , ))              'MINIFS
=MAX(INDEX(C$2:C$6+(A$2:A$6<>F2)*-1E+99, , ))             'MAXIFS
```

[image]